# Understanding a function with modulo in Javascript

Tags: javascript, modulo

I had this code written by a user here yesterday and I'm having trouble understanding it. I understand all by line 9 of the deal function, it creates a random card out of 52 numbers but on the next line I don't understand what this does. Could somebody please explain what this code does so I could modify it and expand on it?

```
//Creates the deck
var Ace = 1;
var Face = 10;
var deck = [Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Face, Face, Face];
/*Creates a deal function that can deal cards to each player. 
Use object_name.property_name = deal() to call this function.*/
var deal = function () {
    var randomcard = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    return deck[Math.floor(randomcard % 13)];
};
```

Comment: Might as well just do `Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)` because this is a trick deck with only 13 cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first let's correct the code. The original code does give you a working result, but it does it in a confusing way. It doesn't pick a value between 0 and 51 which would be the natural thing to do, it picks a value between 2 and 53. (The result is still useful for getting a value between 0 and 12 to use for a value, but getting the suit for the card is not very straight forward.)

```
var randomcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
return deck[randomcard % 13];
```

The modulo operator gets the reminder from a division, so the result from the expression would get the value for the card. Up to 12 it returns the number itself, then at 13 it starts over at 0 again.

---

To get the index for the suit for the card, you would use `Math.floor(randomcard / 13)`. With the original random value (2 to 53) you would have needed to use `(Math.floor(randomcard / 13) % 4)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are 52 cards in the deck. 13 different values with 4 different suit( clubs/diamonds...). Note 4 * 13 = 52.  The modulus 13 is just there to assure that one of the values from in the deck variables gets picked, and the suit is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of only 13 items -- the cards. 0 through 12.

If you take any number and `% 13` it, you will always get a value between 0 and 12 -- the remainder of a division of that number by 13.  The deck of 52 then `% 13` basically reduces the deck from suit + card to just card.

This could have equally been written as `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13) + 1` instead of 52.  However if the code needs to be expanded to also have a suit, then you might likely

Answer (score 0):

The code is only half-valid. The modulo is poorly selecting the type of card to draw out of the deck, but not the suit the card is. In addition, the code doesn't account for having already dealt out a specific card (it's never removed from the deck), so multiple players could have identical cards.

See this page for information on how deck structure looks in JavaScript:

http://www.brainjar.com/js/cards/default2.asp